# Git hooks and work tree

Tags: git, apache, hook, githooks

I have a problem with Git Hooks on server. I need create new working copy to my Apache web folder from Git repository (web folder and Git repository are on the same server). I have this code in Git hooks repository folder in post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/bash
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/test --git-dir=/projects/project.git checkout -f
```

My problem is that Git create files always from first commit. Any further change (commit) is not reflected in the files. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the branch? `git --work-tree=/var/www/html/test --git-dir=/projects/project.git checkout master -f`

Answer (score 1):

You're running `git checkout -f`, which only ensures that all the tracked files in your working directory match the repository version *for the current commit*.  That command won't advance the working tree to the most recent version.

If you want to advance to the current branch head, you need to add that to the command line:

```
git checkout -f <branchname>
```

For example:

```
git checkout -f master
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.